# compare date greater than equal in scala

Tags: scala

Scenario 1

```
val date1 =  LocalDate.parse("2017-02-07")
val date2 =LocalDate.parse("2017-02-01")
date1.isAfter(date2)
```

Output

```
true
```

Scenerio 2

```
val date1 =  LocalDate.parse("2017-02-07")
val date2 =LocalDate.parse("2017-02-07")
date1.isAfter(date2)
```

Output

```
false
```

I want to return `true` when date is > = "2017-02-07"

Comment: `date1.isEqual(date2) || date1.isAfter(date2)`

Comment: any other way or method in api

Comment: Sure, there's `compareTo()` as @SCouto has pointed out. What keeps you from consulting the [API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) yourself?

Answer (score 8):

Use an OR. afaik, there is no method in the API to do that in a single operation

```
date1.isAfter(date2) || date1.isEqual(date2)
```

Another option:

```
date1.compareTo(date2)  >=0
```

Answer (score 4):

After [`import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Ordering$$Implicits$.html), you can just write `date1 >= date2` (you might need `(date1: ChronoLocalDate) >= (date2: ChronoLocalDate)` because `LocalDate` implements `Comparable<ChronoLocalDate>` instead of `Comparable<LocalDate>`, can't check at the moment).

Comment: what does import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._ does

Comment: Imports the implicits which define `>` and other operators given implicit `Ordering`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to enable ordering for `LocalDate` is to make use of implicit conversion to `Long` (via `toEpochDay()`) which has well-defined ordering:

```
import java.time.LocalDate
val date1 = LocalDate.parse("2017-02-07")
val date2 = LocalDate.parse("2017-02-07")

import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._
implicit def localDateOrderer: Ordering[LocalDate] = Ordering.by(d => d.toEpochDay)

date1 >= date2
// res1: Boolean = true
```

Answer (score 2):

One of my favorite approaches dealing with LocalDate comparison is using an `implicit class`. You can think an `implicit class` just like extension method in C#.

You can define the implicit class as below:

```
import org.joda.time.{Days, LocalDate}

object LocalDateExtension {
  class LocalDateExtension(a: LocalDate) {
    def dayDiff(b: LocalDate): Int = {
      Days.daysBetween(a, b).getDays.abs
    }

    def >(b: LocalDate): Boolean = {
      a.isAfter(b)
    }

    def >=(b: LocalDate): Boolean = {
      a.isAfter(b) || a.isEqual(b)
    }

    def <(b: LocalDate): Boolean = {
      a.isBefore(b)
    }

    def <=(b: LocalDate): Boolean = {
      a.isBefore(b) || a.isEqual(b)
    }
  }

  implicit def extendLocalDate(a: LocalDate) = new LocalDateExtension(a)
}
```

Then you can use the extension just like this:

```
val a = LocalDate("2010-04-29")
val b = LocalDate("2010-04-29")

print(a > b) // false
print(a >= b) // true
print(a < b) // false
print(a <= b) // true
```

Hope you will find it useful.

Here is [my blog post](https://diary-of-programmer.blogspot.com/2020/03/dealing-with-joda-time-localdate.html) related to this.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with to tackle similar case with a single operation is:

1. Swap vals and 2. Negate result

Scenerio 2

```
val date1 = LocalDate.parse("2017-02-07")
val date2 = LocalDate.parse("2017-02-07")

!date2.isAfter(date1) // equiv. date1.isAfter(date2) || date1.isEqual(date2)
```